# Is it haram to earn from tiktok clipping?

Tags: money

This thread is going to be a little long to explain everything but essentially what this business model is you find content across youtube or twitch or kick and you take a clip or a portion of the video or content on these platforms and basically post them on tiktok in hopes to make money, of course you need to modify it by adding subtitles and whatnot to have a good retention on the content.

The income is derived from creativity program on tiktok which is around $1/k usually (I'm not even sure if that's haram or halal no one commented as of yet if this is halal)

But there has been a long argument across twitter if this is even ethical or not, you got a creator called "Musa" which basically promotes this business model and he's earning quite a lot, he's a muslim too.

But when you search his name + ethical/unethical you find this, making this questionable.
https://twitter.com/search?q=%40musamanzz%20ethical&src=typed_query
https://twitter.com/search?q=%20%40musamanzz%20unethical&src=typed_query

He even got community noted - https://twitter.com/musamanzz/status/1728755318191186165

You even get people who are frustrated by this for example - https://www.youtube.com/shorts/S91KaW3ZVtc

There are more too.

Now creativity program is getting paid based on views, i know that youtube adsense is haram cause your getting paid with ads which may contain haram.
But even with creativity program your getting paid with the revenue from tiktok which is mostly haram (ads containing music/tiktok lives which might induce degeneracy a lot of the time it does that) and overall a haram platform as the haram in it outweighs the halal, your getting paid with there money and in a way doing a service for them for popularizing a haram app which they compensate you for in return.
I still am not sure whether creativity program is haram or not as no sheikh i know of has been asked this as of yet.

And to be fair here some of these tiktok clippers do a great service to islam, cause they repurpose content that is islamic and dawah related like sheikh uthman and so on which promotes islam to many. So i guess there are positives to it but a lot also don't like this.

Big portion of tiktok are just clips of streamers/content creators/repurposed content already uploaded on sites outside of tiktok and people are making a lot from this? Is income halal or haram?

Also if you going to advise me to reach out to the creator and ask him then that's practically impossible because these creators have a following and millions and it's not practical for me to directly ask.

Cause it's not solely about creators even like repurosed videos from youtube from old videos which there are no creator i can directly reach out to, for example this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EqSXDwTq6U

Would like to know the permissibility for this, and if it should be avoided. Thank you.